# Question mark Typescript variable

Tags: mongodb, typescript, typescript2.0

I've seen code snippets like these:

```
export interface IUser {
    email?: string;
    firstName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
}
```

But why are the variable names suffixed by a question mark? This snippet is part of an example of using mongodb with Typescript.

The answer is probably somewhere out there but I seem to be using the wrong keywords since I can't find it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In TypeScript, `<name>?: <typename>` a shorthand for `<name>: <typename> | undefined`.

This indicates to the type system that a symbol *may* contain a value of the indicated type or it *may* contain the value `undefined` (which is like `null`).

This is important when the (new in TypeScript 2) `--strictNullChecks` option is enabled.   The documentation on [Null- and undefined-aware types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html) option is probably where you should start to understand why this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

It means they can be there but dont have to be. It allows for optional field names. It can be quite common to use.

An example use is allowing users on a website to have an optional display name.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaked, its to indicate that its optional, that means that it can be null.